# Set a javascript object property while calling a method that relies on it

Tags: javascript, function, object, properties, methods

Here is a really lame example of what I am trying to do.  This piece of code works.

```
var Love = {
  name: 'Johnny',
  kiss: function (girl){
    alert(this.name + " kissed " + girl );
  }
};

Love.name = "Chris";
Love.kiss("Becky");
```

I first reassigned the property of name, and then called the method sending my parameter

What I would really like to do, is use JSON to set the "name" property while calling the method.  I swear I've seen it done somewhere, but I can't figure it out.  So ideally it would look something like this.

```
Love.kiss({
  name: 'Chris'},
  "Becky");
```

Or even something like this.

```
var Love = {
  Guy: 'Johnny',
  Girl: 'Mallory',
  kiss: function (){
    alert(this.Guy + " kissed " + this.girl);
  }
};

Love.kiss({
  Guy: 'Chris',
  Girl; 'Becky'});
```

Again, I know this is a really stupid example, but the concept has a certain application that I would like to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run through the keys of the object you pass in as an argument and assign them to `this`:

```
var Love = {
    Guy: 'Johnny',
    Girl: 'Mallory',
    kiss: function(opts) {
        for (var k in opts) {
            this[k] = opts[k];
        }
        alert(this.Guy + " kissed " + this.Girl);
    }
};

Love.kiss({
    Guy: 'Chris',
    Girl: 'Becky'
});​  // -> alert('Chris kissed Becky')
```

### [See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upcxN/)

Comment: Note: you also probably want to wrap the `for` loop in `if (typeof opts !== 'undefined')` so you can also call `Love.kiss()` without an argument.

Answer (score 2):

You want to pass an object literal (not JSON!) to the function anyway, so why not use it directly?

```
function kiss(obj) {
    alert(obj.Guy + " kissed " + obj.Girl);
}

kiss({
    Guy: 'Chris',
    Girl: 'Becky'
});
```

Why even use the `Love` object?

Comment: this is a great example.  I'm glad you gave some feedback.  I guess the only reason I would want to have the love object is so that I could have "default" properties set if nothing was set during the call.

Comment: You can add the default values inside `kiss` if needed. And the solution by @mVChr should work too, if you decide to keep the object.

Comment: yes @mVChr's solution does exactly what I need.  Takes whatever values I send it, but will also perform the function with the default values.  You all have been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
var Love = {
  Guy: 'Johnny',
  Girl: 'Mallory',
  kiss: function( data ) {
    this.Guy = data.Guy;
    this.Girl = data.Girl;
    alert(this.Guy + " kissed " + this.Girl);
  }
};

Love.kiss({
  Guy: 'Chris',
  Girl: 'Becky'
});
```

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: thank you for your input, this is a helpful demonstration, and the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

```
var Love = {
  Guy: 'Johnny',
  Girl: 'Mallory',

  kiss: function (obj){
    // if you want default values you can use ||
    this.Guy = obj.Guy || this.Guy;
    this.Girl = obj.Girl || this.Girl;

    alert(this.Guy + " kissed " + this.Girl);

    // or change the code above to the following if you don't want to store new values
    var guy = obj.Guy || this.Guy,
        girl = obj.Girl || this.Girl;

    alert(guy + " kissed " + girl);
  }
};

Love.kiss({
  Guy: 'Chris',
  Girl: 'Becky'
});
```